# How do I add repeating dates programmatically?

Tags: 7, datetime

I have some JSON data I'm using to populate Drupal 7 database. This involves creating nodes with repeating dates.

This is a sample of the data.

```
 [field_event_date] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [value] => 2012-12-14 10:00:00
                [value2] => 2012-12-14 12:00:00
                [rrule] => RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;INTERVAL=1;UNTIL=20160422T215959Z;WKST=MO
EXDATE:20121221T000000,20130125T000000,20130222T000000,20130329T000000,20130426T000000,20130531T000000,20130628T000000,20130726T000000,20130830T000000,20130927T000000,20131025T000000,20131129T000000,20131220T000000,20140131T000000,20140228T000000,20140328T000000,20140425T000000
                [timezone] => Europe/London
                [timezone_db] => Europe/London
                [date_type] => datetime
            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [value] => 2012-12-28 10:00:00
                [value2] => 2012-12-28 12:00:00
                [rrule] => RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;INTERVAL=1;UNTIL=20160422T215959Z;WKST=MO
EXDATE:20121221T000000,20130125T000000,20130222T000000,20130329T000000,20130426T000000,20130531T000000,20130628T000000,20130726T000000,20130830T000000,20130927T000000,20131025T000000,20131129T000000,20131220T000000,20140131T000000,20140228T000000,20140328T000000,20140425T000000
                [timezone] => Europe/London
                [timezone_db] => Europe/London
                [date_type] => datetime
            )
    )
```

How could I enter this data into the table which stores the date for this node type?

Answer (score 0):

Add [] to the end of the data field.

eg.

```
    foreach($vals->field_event_date as $fed){
        //notice the []!
        $node->field_date_of_event['und'][]= array(
            'data1' => $fed->data1,
            'data2' => $fed->data2            
        )
    }
```